# disable tomcat deployed application gui (axis 2)

Tags: tomcat, apache-axis

Is there a way to disable access to the axis 2 gui inside Tomcat? i.e. disable access to http://myserver/axis2 and not allow access using the standard axis 2 username/password?

I suspect it's a case of editing the axis2.war file, but we want to do it without having to deflate the war and be able to get newer versions (if any are made) without having to worry if we have the correct axis2.war file.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it from tomcat's configuration, but if I explode the axis2.war file, edit the web.xml and comment out:

```
<servlet-name>AxisAdminServlet</servlet-name>
<display-name>Apache-Axis AxisAdmin Servlet (Web Admin)</display-name>
<servlet-class>
        org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

it works a treat.